# Proximity Beacon API Register EID-Frame

Tags: google-api, beacon, google-beacon-platform, eid

I'm currently working with the Google Proximity Beacon API, especially with the EID-Frame. I was able to register an eid-frame by taking the type "EDDYSTONE", but it is saved with the beacon id "beacons/3!beaconid".

The [API-Reference](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/) clearly says that the type of the `AdvertisedId` should contain the type "EDDYSTONE_EID" ([see here](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/v1beta1/AdvertisedId)). Sadly, requests with this type get a error response (see picture).

So if I want to resolve an eid, I should search for a beacon with a beacon-id like "beacons/4!beaconId(eid)" ([see here](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/v1beta1/beacons/get)). Since I wasn't able to register it with the eid type, how will I be able to resolve it?

For more information feel free to comment. All information in the request are pseudo values, except the `service_ecdh_puplic_key`.

[image: Error Response on eid register with type EDDYSTONE_EID]

Answer (score 0):

When registering an Eddystone-EID, the `AdvertisedId` field should be a valid Eddystone-UID.  See here: https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/register#register_an_eddystone-eid_beacon

This UID forms the `beaconName`, once your EID is registered.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you register a beacon using EID, it will be saved in your google dashboard and the beacon will be recognized by "beacons/3!...".

But if you want to get the info of this beacon, you may use "beacons/4!+EID" then google resolver will return the beacon that you expect.